# three.js - building Geometry manually, out of range vertices attribute 2

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to build some geometry myself rather than using a three.js primitive. I've added vertices and faces, and I've checked that none of the face indices exceed the vertex count.

So geo.vertices is filled with an array of THREE.Vector3.

Then tried adding UVs by doing:

```
geo.faceVertexUVs = [];
for( i = 0; i < numVertex; i++ ) {
  // (calc u, v here)
  geo.faceVertexUVs.push(new THREE.Vector2(u,v));
}
geo.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
geo.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
```

Then I'm building each face & normal like this:

```
geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(
  i0, i1, i2,
  new THREE.Vector3(nx,ny,nz),
  clr, 0
));

// then create a mesh

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geo, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  shading:THREE.FlatShading, color:0xFFFFFF, map:tex
}));

geo.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
geo.uvsNeedUpdate = true;

scene.add(mesh);
```

Then when I try to render I get the error "attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2". Which attribute is #2?

Comment: For one thing, it should be `geo.faceVertexUVs[ 0 ].push(). Also, remove the `needsUpdate` flags, and add them back only if needed.

Comment: Thanks West. I've also realized that I can also look at PlaneGeometry.js as an example to follow. Does faceVertexUVs[0] correspond to material 0?